# "git stash save -u" is not removing some directories

Tags: git, git-stash

here's my situation:
Say I work on branch b1. I write a file dir/f1. 
Then I want integrate code of dir/f1 in dir/f2, and I no longer need f1. 
For random reason I want to keep f1.
I removed it from version control, but it is still here, untracked.
If I switch to branch b2, f1 has compile errors, since it has not been kept in sync with b2.
So, I decided to git stash -u in b1 before switching so I can get my context back when I'm done working on b2.
It works almost as expected: working dir is cleaned up, everything (tracked and untracked files, but not ignored files since I didn't use -a) is stashed, and I can git stash apply them back.
The only problem is some files are removed from working dir, but others are not. 
The message is:

```
Not removing dir/f1
```

So my question is: what can be the reason for such a behavior? How does git decide which files are to be removed during a stash and which are not?
Thanks

Comment: I am afraid git man page contains no information about -u flag.

Answer (score 1):

Such a behavior seems to be possible only with `git 1.7.7.x` and when `dir/f1` is a directory.

`git stash -u` uses `git clean` for removing the files from working directory. According to [git's source code](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/clean.c#L168), the only case `git clean` could respond with the `Not removing dir/f1` message is when `dir/f1` is a directory. Are you sure `dir/f1` was a file?

Starting with `git 1.7.8` (specifically, with [this commit](http://github.com/git/git/commit/7474b8b452f2600bd2a9e03f67b83b489aeadb37)), `git stash -u` passes the `-d` option to `git clean`, so such a problem would no longer occur.